# Make a call from VB6 to WEBAPI

Tags: vb6

Can someone help me how to make a WebApi call from VB6.I found few but nothing help. The Following is the Url https://samplewebsiteurl/EnterpriseParticipant, and this is the request it expecting

```
{
"Client": "YYYA",
"Platforms" :  [],
"ProgramIdentifier": "",
"MapToEnterpriseView": "true",
"ParticipantRequest": {
   "FirstName" : "",
   "LastName": "Test"
}
}
```

And below is the VB6 code i found. How should i pass the request through VB6 to call WebApi? Any references i need to use?

```
Dim WinHttpReq As Object, status As String, response As String 
On Error GoTo errorfound 
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" ;) 
WinHttpReq.open "POST", url, False 
WinHttpReq.send
```

Comment: Your "found" code looks like awkwardly converted VBScript.  But (a.) you didn't send your JSON, and (b.) POST normally expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for Content-Type which means you have to format the payload that way first anyway.  To do that you need to know what element name the server expects, do the UrlEncoding, etc.

Comment: Of course the server might also accept raw JSON if it will take `application/json` instead.

Comment: @Bob77

I found few and i am new to VB6

    Set myMSXML = New MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
    myMSXML.open "POST", URL, True
    myMSXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-
    form-urlencoded"
    myMSXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Firefox 3.6.4"
    myMSXML.OnReadyStateChange = (Shown below)
    myMSXML.send YourPostDataString

Comment: @Bob77 do you have a sample VB6 code which will help me.

Comment: That object isn't great for API calls because it works through the UrlMon/IE cache.  Changing horses doesn't change the path you need to ride anyway.

Comment: Without the definition of this API we can only guess at the actual requirements.

Comment: @Bob77 Define definition of this API?

Comment: Normally you are given things that tell you what HTTP methods can be used and what Content-Type and character encoding and such are expected and returned.  That also includes things like the "form" element name(s) as well depending on how a POST is handled.

Comment: For my webapi the response content type is 'application/hal+json'

Comment: What about the request Content-Type?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the most simple example:

```
Option Explicit

'Reference to:
'
'   Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1

Private Req As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    With Req
        .Open "POST", "http://localhost:8080/SomeAPI", Async:=False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/hal+json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/*, application/hal+json, application/json"
        'Note: Normally you don't include all of this whitespace, but
        'we'll use it in this example:
        .Send "{" & vbCrLf _
            & """Client"": ""YYYA""," & vbCrLf _
            & """Platforms"":  []," & vbCrLf _
            & """ProgramIdentifier"": """"," & vbCrLf _
            & """MapToEnterpriseView"": ""true""," & vbCrLf _
            & """ParticipantRequest"": {" & vbCrLf _
            & "   ""FirstName"" : """"," & vbCrLf _
            & "   ""LastName"": ""Test""" & vbCrLf _
            & "}" & vbCrLf _
            & "}"
        Label1.Caption = CStr(.Status) & " " & .StatusText & vbNewLine _
                       & .GetAllResponseHeaders() & vbNewLine _
                       & String$(40, "-") & vbNewLine _
                       & .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set Req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked, now i am looking for Json to Object converter. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Wasnt happy with the answer here.
So here a simple example for a PUT request.

```
Sub API_TEST()
'
Dim objWinHTTP
Set objWinHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")


    objWinHTTP.Open "PUT", "https://localhost:5001/api/?department=DDBB&changenumber=1337&isNew=1"
    objWinHTTP.SetTimeouts 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000


    Call objWinHTTP.Send(psData)
    MsgBox (objWinHTTP.Status)
    If objWinHTTP.Status <> 200 Then

    MsgBox ("Something went wrong.")

    End If
   
End Sub
```